# Extract Array with objects that exists from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I'm using firebase data-base.

After deleting an object, snapshot will return an array with a length longer than the actual array values:

```
fireBase.ref(REFS_CATEGORIES_ONE_TIMERS).once('value', function (snapshot) {
            const values = snapshot.val(); // This array will contain 2 valus with leanth of 3
            returnFunc(extract);
 });
```

Array content:

```
myArray[0] : SomeObject;
myArray[2] : SomeObject;
```

When looping over this array, it will loop 3 times, on time the value will be undefined.

How can I **remove missing entries** in an more 'elegant' way than looping over?

Comment: I've tried looping and checking in undefined, but I'm looking for a better option

Comment: voted to reopen - the problem statement is clear

Comment: @MCMatan I've re-edited the question slightly, because there is a very distinct (and important) semantic difference between an "undefined value" as your edited version had written, and a "missing entry".  It's possible for `myArray[1]` to actually hold the value `undefined`, but at that point it's no longer strictly missing.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for your notice 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function will only process elements with keys that exist in the array, so calling that with a callback that always returns `true` will suffice:

```
var extract = myarray.filter(_ => true);
```

The resulting array will have contiguous indices, with the missing entries removed and any following entries "collapsed" down into the gap left by them.

Comment: Is _ a best practice than () when no argument is needed ?

Comment: @UlysseBN I wouldn't argue that it's "best", but it's no worse than using `e => true` whilst ignoring the value of `e`, and uses the common semantic of `_` for an unused variable, and it's also shorter than `() =>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to test if the index is in the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i in array) {
        // do something with array[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: This syntax also works: `for (i in array)  { doStuffWith = a[i] }`

Comment: @UlysseBN using `for .. in` on arrays is frowned upon, because it'll also go through any enumerable non-numeric properties of the array.

Comment: Right. I got this approach from the polyfill in the Array.prototype.filter MDN page.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, that's also how I knew that `filter` could be used to do this :)

Answer (score -1):

Below are 3 approaches, I have tried.

```js
var UNDEFINED = undefined;
var UNDEFINED_STR = 'undefined';

var sampleWithOutEmpty = [10, 'hello', null, {}];
var sampleWithEmpty = [, 10, 'hello', , null, {}];

function allAllSlotsFilled (sample){
 /* 
  1.
  check if filtered values that are NOT UNDEFINED is equal to the length of the orignal array ... 
  if the lenghts aren't same then the array EMPTY slots.
 */
 var result = (sample.filter(element => { return typeof(element) !== UNDEFINED_STR;}).length  === sample.length);
 console.log(result);

 /*  
  2.
  sort array in descending order. undefined gets pushed to the last. 
  Then check if the last item is undefined.
  if YES the array has empty slots.
 */
 sample.sort()
 result = (typeof(sample[sample.length -1]) !== UNDEFINED_STR); 
 console.log(result);

 /*
  3.
  Using sets. Create a set with elements in array. Then check is UNDEFINED is a element in set.
  If YES the array has empty slots.
 */
 var set = new Set(sample);
 result = !set.has(UNDEFINED);
 console.log(result);

}

allAllSlotsFilled(sampleWithOutEmpty);
allAllSlotsFilled(sampleWithEmpty);
```

Comment: The OP didn't want to know _if_ the array has missing keys, he wanted a new copy that's contiguous without any missing keys.  Also, the code you do have looks for undefined _values_, and not missing keys.  There's a semantic difference between `[0,,2]` and `[0, undefined, 2]`.  In the latter the key 1 _does exist_, but has an _`undefined`_ value.